# How to toggle all .class elements in the parent container

Tags: jquery, html

I have a parent container with a lot of elements. I need to toggle some of them by clicking a button located in this container, here's an example

```
<div class="my-container">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <div class="toggle-me visible">1</div>
    <div class="toggle-me hidden">2</div>
    <div>
         <strong>Press me</strong>
         <button class="i-am-toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you please advice how to toggle elements by class only in the same as button's container with jQuery?

Comment: what do you want to toggle?

Comment: I need to toggle .visible and .hidden elements' display property.

Comment: So you want to replace .visible with .hidden and .hidden with .visible?

Comment: I don't know which option is better - remove and add class or just toggle visibility with jquery.toggle. But the point is to hide elements with the .visible class and show .hidden only in the same as button's parent container.

Comment: always helpful to include criteria like `instance only` in question... I got lucky and assumed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
$('.i-am-toggle').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.my-container').find('.toggle-me').toggle();    
});
```

Assumes you have multiple "my-container" and want to only toggle instances of `visible` and `hidden` class within the specific container

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it:

```
$(".i-am-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".toggle-me").toggle();
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t43ouwe4/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code... do you mean like this

```js
$('.i-am-toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('.my-container div.toggle-me').toggle();
})
```

```css
.visible{
  display:block;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-container">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <div class="toggle-me visible" >1</div>
    <div class="toggle-me hidden">2</div>
    <div>
         <strong>Press me</strong>
         <button class="i-am-toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method to find parents relative to your button element.  Try something like this:

```
$('.i-am-toggle').click(function(e){
    $(this).parents('.my-container').find('.toggle-me').toggleClass('visible').toggleClass('hidden');        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".i-am-toggle").
   on("click", function () {
      $(this).parentsUntil("#myContainer")
       .find("div.toggle-me").toggleClass("visible hidden");
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5m9j8zm/)